# How to use WinJS and Typescript together? Case: WinJS class vs Typescript class

Tags: typescript, winjs

In WinJS I declare class like that:

```
WinJS.Namespace.define('MyNamespace', {
    MyClass: WinJS.Class.define(function ctor() {
        //constructor
    },
    {
        //instance members
    },
    {
        //static members
    })
});
```

But in Typescript I use:

```
module MyNamespace {
    class MyClass {
        constructor() {

        }
    }
}
```

So, I want to use the require/import behavior of Typescript in a WinJS project. What is the best approach for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use TypeScript, then you should use TypeScript's classes/interfaces/modules.  This will allow you to get all the benefits of static typing that TypeScript provides.

Note: You could still get the benefits with WinJS.Class, but you would need to create an interface for the classes that you could then use to tell the TypeScript compiler the type.  It would be more explicit, and you could easily forget to do it in places and miss out on the added benefits of typing.

Answer (score 0):

See the [WinJS.Utilities.requireSupportedForProcessing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967820.aspx) . According to this you can use classic TypeScript module and class definition. For example:

```
module AnyModule
{
  export class AnyClass
  {
    constructor()
    {

    }

    public AnyMethod()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

and then mark this class (who is de facto function) to processing in the declarative code by calling [WinJS.Utilities.markSupportedForProcessing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967819.aspx). After this simple modification:

```
module AnyModule
{
  export class AnyClass
  {
    constructor()
    {

    }

    public AnyMethod()
    {
    }
  }
  WinJS.Utilities.markSupportedForProcessing(AnyClass);
}
```

You can use this way for classic function:

```
module AnyModule
{
  function AnyFunc()
  {
  }
  WinJS.Utilities.markSupportedForProcessing(AnyFunc);
}
```

. Calling the WinJS.Utilities.requireSupportedForProcessing method can then be used to validate the registration.
If you don't need to use the class or function in the declarative call, then calling the WinJS.Utilities.markSupportedForProcessing(...) can be omited.